# Mysql fetching everyday's last inserted record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data stored in MySql database daily at different times within a day.
Now I want to select the last inserted row for each day for a range of days and I want to do this in single query.
How can this be done in a single query ?
Below is schema example where I want to find last inserted stock value for a particular company within a particular range of dates like from 7/20 to 7/29 and this last inserted value should be for every day

```
Table Shares

id - Primary key
company_name- varchar
datetime - timestamp
stockvalue - varchar
```

Comment: Some DB schema example would be nice.

Comment: SELECT stockvalue WHERE company_name = 'xyzabc' AND some_date_field BETWEEN 2014-07-20 AND 2014-07-29 (for the range); ORDER BY some_date_field LIMIT 1...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM shares ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```